# why <link rel="import" href=""> requires server and <link rel="stylesheet" href=""> is not

Tags: html

To import a html file, here is the procedure

```
<link rel="import" href="">
```

To import a css file, here is the procedure

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
```

why  importing html requires server and importing css file doesn't

Comment: Unclear of what exactly you are asking.  Care to elarborate?

Comment: Take a look at these guides [w3c import](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) and [html5rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/)

Comment: Generally, if i linked a stylesheet in index.html, this works fine when i open the index.html directly. But, the html imports are not working if i open the index.html directly since it requires server. Why? @sid